# Formatting a table html/css

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table created via Javascript and displaying correctly. The relevant code for table creation:

```html
 var uns="<td bgcolor='#99FFCC'><button type='button' name='"+listy.get_item(i).get_id()+"' onclick='rh(\""+i+"\")'>Check blood</button>   true</td>"
 var tabbela+="<tr id='"+listy.get_item(i).get_id()+"<td></td><td></td>"+uns+</tr>;
```

On the button click the rh() function needs to change the style and content of this particular `<td>`

I can retrieve the `<tr>`

```js
var tr=document.getElementById(listy.get_item(list_id).get_id());
 tr.style.backgroundColor="#94B84D";
```

but changing the background color for whole `<tr>` changes it only for `<td>`s without their own style assigned. I am guessing this is by design.

How can I change the color and content of the `<td>`?  It is always the 5th `<td>` in this `<tr>`. I tried:

```js
tr.children('td:eq(5)').style.backgroundColor="#94B84D";
```

but nothing happens. I would be very happy with a possibility of changing the whole html (the whole `var uns`) of this `<td>`.

Please help.

Comment: Please create a FIDDLE.

Comment: `tr.cells[4].style.backgroundColor='#94B84D';`. Changing content (value of `td`) like examples above but using `tr.cells[4].innerHTML='some text';`

Comment: works :) Could you please post it as an answer so that I could accept it?